# How to find this type limit which has polynomial in sqrt?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I have no idea to find the below limit

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{2\sqrt{9n^2+20n+10}-6n-5}{\sqrt{9n^2+20n+10}-3n-5}=?$$

Comment: try to rationalize the denominator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Did you try to get rid of the square root in the denominator?

Remember:

$$\frac{A}{\sqrt{B} + C} = \frac{A(\sqrt{B}-C)}{B-C^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since the square root portions in both the numerator and denominator are the same, I would think about factoring out the numerator. Note that:

$$2 \sqrt{9n^2 + 20n + 10} - 6n - 10 = 2(\sqrt{9n^2 + 20n + 10} - 3n - 5) $$

After you separate your numerator appropriately, then the answer should be more obvious.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{2\sqrt{9n^2+20n+10}-6n-5}{\sqrt{9n^2+20n+10}-3n-5}=\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{2(\sqrt{9n^2+20n+10}-3n-5) + 5}{\sqrt{9n^2+20n+10}-3n-5} \\ = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\left( \frac{2(\sqrt{9n^2+20n+10}-3n-5)}{\sqrt{9n^2+20n+10}-3n-5} + \frac{5}{\sqrt{9n^2+20n+10}-3n-5}\right) \\ =2 +\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{5}{\sqrt{9n^2+20n+10}-(3n+5)} \\ = 
2 +\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{5(\sqrt{9n^2+20n+10}+(3n+5))}{9n^2+20n+10-(3n+5)^2}$$(I multiplied the numerator denominator by the denominator's conjugate)
$$ \\= 2+\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{5\sqrt{9n^2+20n+10} + 15n + 25}{-10n - 15} 
\\=2+\lim_{{1 \over n} \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{9+{20\over n}+ {10 \over n^2}} + 3 + {5\over n}}{-2 - {3\over n}}$$
(multiplying numerator and denominator by $1\over {5n}$, and using the fact that ${1\over n} \to 0^+$ as $n \to +\infty$)

$$ 
\\=2+ \frac{3 + 3}{-2} = -1
$$

Comment: When you get to the next-to-the-last line, I think you want to divide by $5n$ to get $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{9+\frac{20}{n}+\frac{10}{n^2}}+3+\frac{5}{n}}{-2-3/n}$

Comment: oh, i misread the limit :S You're right, i'll add that now

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{2\sqrt{9n^2+20n+10}-6n-5}{\sqrt{9n^2+20n+10}-3n-5}\;,$ Now Let $\displaystyle n=\frac{1}{y}$ So when $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\;,$ Then $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}$

So Limit $\displaystyle \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{2\sqrt{10y^2+20y+9}-5y-6}{\sqrt{10y^2+20y+9}-5y-3} = \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{2\cdot \sqrt{10}y[1+\left(\frac{20y+9}{10}\right)]^{\frac{1}{2}}-5y-6}{ \sqrt{10}y[1+\left(\frac{20y+9}{10}\right)]^{\frac{1}{2}}-5y-3}$

Now Using $\displaystyle (1+x)^{n} = 1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)x^2}{2!}+......\infty$